# Call REGEXP_LIKE using LINQ to Entities with Oracle

Tags: regex, linq, oracle, entities

So if I have an Oracle query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col1, '^[0-9]+$');
```

How can I call `REGEXP_LIKE` using LINQ to Entities with the Oracle.DataAccess client:

```
var q = from x in collection
        where ??Oracle.REGEXP_LIKE(x.col1, "^[0-9]+$")??
        select x;
```

Is something like this supported with the Oracle.DataAccess client?

Comment: Did you try **where Regex.IsMatch(x.col1, "^[0-9]+$")** ?

Comment: Yes, but then I get the error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ... and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for me was just to open up a connection to the DB (ADO.NET) and execute the raw SQL...I dabbled with trying to create a custom LINQ function, but it would've taken too long to figure out given the relative simplicity of just "hacking" it.